# Read Return Object in JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

Read Return Object in JQuery
4 minutes ago|LINK

I have created a wcf service that return a GenericList Object. I need to read that object on Client side using Jquery but can get it working:

below is my code:

svc Method:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public CommentList GetComments()
    {
        Comments oComment1 = new Comments();
        oComment1.Title = "AMaking hay when the sun shines";
        oComment1.Author = "Plan_A";
        oComment1.CommentText = "AI like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking";

        Comments oComment2 = new Comments();
        oComment2.Title = "Making hay when the sun shines";
        oComment2.Author = "Plan_B";
        oComment2.CommentText = "I like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking";

        CommentList oCommentList = new CommentList();
        oCommentList.Comment.Add(oComment1);
        oCommentList.Comment.Add(oComment2);

        return oCommentList;
    }
```

Jquery script on Client side:

```
$('#CommentsButton').click(function () {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:55679/RESTService.svc/GetComments?callback=?', function (data) {
                 alert(data);

        });
```

Response i am getting (through Inspect element - Chrome tool)

```
jsonp1363710839478({"Comment":[{"Author":"Plan_A","CommentText":"AI like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking","Title":"AMaking hay when the sun shines"},{"Author":"Plan_B","CommentText":"I like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking","Title":"Making hay when the sun shines"}]});
```

Comment: and the question is what?

Comment: Where is `GetComments` defined in `alert(GetComments);`?

Comment: @Matus I need to read the values getting from the Getcomments function defined in code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:55679/RESTService.svc/GetComments?callback=?', function (data) {
    alert(data.Comments[0].Author);
});
```

Comment: not sure that '&' is valid, but I'm not sure about the 'callback=?' either. :)

Comment: @DavinTryon the callback is for jsonp, and the as for the "&" not sure how his url is constructed, just figured he was trying to pass as a parameter. :S

Comment: It looks like you have changed the '?' to '&' in the url. Was that intentional?  Because usually you would see `http://host/action?var=value`

Comment: @DennisMartinez  tried but get the following output: [ Object object]

Comment: @Khan try this: `alert(data.Comments[0].Author);` it looks like you're passing back an array of objects. You'll have to iterate through the array and grab the property inside each object you want to utilize.

Comment: @DennisMartinez Tried and getting error, "Cannot read property 0 of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        url : 'http://localhost:55679/RESTService.svc/GetComments',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.Comment.length);
            for(var i=0; i<data.Comment.length; i++){
                console.log(data.Comment[i].Title);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Khan, I created a sample WCF server and tested it before posting. Surely it works.... (have you opened the console window in your browser (see `console.log` in the code). or replace it with `alert`)